# How to check if main parameter exist and validate it in C++

Tags: c++

If I wanted to validate if the user has entered a specific parameter to the program how would I do it? This is my current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

    if (argv[1] == "--para") {
        std::cout << "Some text here..." << std::endl;
    }

}
```

The code above will not work because I need some way to convert the parameter to a string so I can validate it in my if statement.

What I do not know is how to check if the --para exists at all when using multiple parameters into the program.

**Example:**

```
./main parameter1 parameter2 --para
```

Comment: Seriously, it _really_ helps to learn something about C before diving in and trying to do something. Otherwise you are in for a world of pain.

Comment: @dandan78: Well, it _really_ helps if you could elaborate. Maybe it could guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Well, I see questions of this sort question depressingly often. What it tells me is that there are people want to program in C or C++ and but don't even bother to read a tutorial or two on the subject beforehand. On Stackoverflow, the assumption is that you've done your homework first before asking your question, which you clearly have not. That being the case, you're on your own.

Comment: See [Boost.Program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/program_options.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can construct and use a `std::vector` of `std::strings` directly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> params{argv, argv+argc};

    for (auto i : params)
        if (i == "--para") {
            std::cout << "Some text here..." << std::endl;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to know if at least one of the parameters was a match you could use a standard library algorithm to check for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> params{argv, argv+argc};
    const std::string para{"--para"};

    if (std::any_of(params.begin(),params.end(),[&para](std::string val) {return val==para; }))
            std::cout << "Some text here..." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That won't handle multiple parameters (argc > 2)

Comment: @FrankPuffer Why not?

Comment: The text "--para" is not neccessarily the 1st argument, see the example at the end of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the check in a loop:

```
for( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ ) {
    if (strcmp(argv[i], "--para") == 0) {
        std::cout << "Some text here..." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Instead of using `strcmp` you can convert the character pointer to a string:

```
for( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ ) {
    std::string str(argv[i]); 
    if (str ==  "--para") {
        std::cout << "Some text here..." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `==` when checking from `const char*` equality! use `strcmp` or construct an `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in pure c using [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/). For example to check first parameter:

```
if(argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "--para") == 0) {
// do some stuff here
}
```

You can just loop over other arguments and apply the same logic to check others

Comment: That won't handle multiple parameters (argc > 2).

Comment: Edited. Didn't notice that part of the question

Answer (score 0):

This is a solved problem.  There are lots of libraries out there.  I like argp, but it's gnu specific (I think).  It's also C, not C++, but can be made to work.  Boost has a utility for this also.  I'm sure there are dozens of others.  Don't reinvent the wheel.

http://optionparser.sourceforge.net/

http://tclap.sourceforge.net/

[boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/program_options.html)

[What parameter parser libraries are there for C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253556/what-parameter-parser-libraries-are-there-for-c)

Comment: Basically true, but depending on what the OP wants to do, these libraries might be overkill. Using a library can have disadvantages as well.

Comment: @FrankPuffer: Absolutely agree.  Flatmouse's answer is the one I upvoted, I think it's best of those here (after modification in response to your comment).  I wanted to offer another set of solutions to this problem, and try to give further insight for future searchers, not just the OP.