# Pass arguments into C program from command line

Tags: c, linux, arguments

So I'm in Linux and I want to have a program accept arguments when you execute it from the command line.

For example,

`./myprogram 42 -b -s`

So then the program would store that number 42 as an int and execute certain parts of code depending on what arguments it gets like -b or -s.

Comment: The canonical format for a command line passes option arguments such as '-b' and '-s' before any non-option arguments such as '42'.  So, the standard, orthodox command line format would be "./myprogram -b -s 42".  Avoid deviating from that standard. [...more in next comment...]

Comment: See section 12 (Utility conventions) of Base Definitions of the POSIX standard at http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/toc.htm.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: The order doesn't matter. `getopt_long` function does the right thing regardless of the order. See my answer.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You could use [getopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html).

```
 #include <ctype.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 
 int
 main (int argc, char **argv)
 {
   int bflag = 0;
   int sflag = 0;
   int index;
   int c;
 
   opterr = 0;
 
   while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "bs")) != -1)
     switch (c)
       {
       case 'b':
         bflag = 1;
         break;
       case 's':
         sflag = 1;
         break;
       case '?':
         if (isprint (optopt))
           fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
         else
           fprintf (stderr,
                    "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n",
                    optopt);
         return 1;
       default:
         abort ();
       }
 
   printf ("bflag = %d, sflag = %d\n", bflag, sflag);
 
   for (index = optind; index < argc; index++)
     printf ("Non-option argument %s\n", argv[index]);
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Shouldn't He/She understand "main arguments passing" first? ;)

Comment: It will work on Linux because the getopt() function is GNU getopt() and you don't normally set POSIXLY_CORRECT in the environment, and GNU getopt() then processes option arguments before 'file' arguments, even when they follow a file argument as in the example.  On POSIX platforms, it won't work....

Comment: ....because the 42 will stop the -b and -s options from being interpreted as options.  Of course, the design of the command line is bad too.  I'll note that in the comments to the question.

Comment: @Jonathan: The question does have the tag `linux`. Therefore GNU `getopt()` example is appropriate here.

Comment: @J F Sebastian - yes, it does have a Linux tag; that's why it has an upvote from me.  The structure of a command line and arguments ordering should not rely on that quirk; well, I still have to work across other platforms, and GNU getopt is not standard on other platforms (for all it is available).

Comment: ...continued...As ever, if you do something consciously, knowing what is happening, it is usually OK.  If you are unaware of it, you get nasty surprises sooner or later.

Answer (score 29):

In C, this is done using arguments passed to your `main()` function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

More information can be found online such as this [Arguments to main](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter10/arguments_to_main.html) article.

Comment: Sorry - that's not a dreadfully good x-ref.  There's a bug in the statement that "The declaration of the argv argument is often a novice programmer's first encounter with pointers to arrays of pointers and can prove intimidating" (argv is an array of pointers, not a pointer to an array of pointers).

Comment: Additionally, the next page shows an ad hoc option parser instead of using the standard getopt() or getopt_long() parsers - which is simply bad advice.  No - it is not a good reference.

Comment: In C, a reference to an array is an address, just like a pointer is an address.  Thus, argv can be referred to as both "an array" and "a pointer to an array".  This is one of the beautiful simplicities of C as well as one of the points of confusions.

Answer (score 10):

Consider using [`getopt_long()`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libc/Getopt-Long-Options.html#Getopt-Long-Options). It allows both short and long options in any combination.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>

/* Flag set by `--verbose'. */
static int verbose_flag;

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  while (1)
    {
      static struct option long_options[] =
    {
      /* This option set a flag. */
      {"verbose", no_argument,       &verbose_flag, 1},
      /* These options don't set a flag.
         We distinguish them by their indices. */
      {"blip",    no_argument,       0, 'b'},
      {"slip",    no_argument,       0, 's'},
      {0,         0,                 0,  0}
    };
      /* getopt_long stores the option index here. */
      int option_index = 0;

      int c = getopt_long (argc, argv, "bs",
               long_options, &option_index);

      /* Detect the end of the options. */
      if (c == -1)
    break;

      switch (c)
    {
    case 0:
      /* If this option set a flag, do nothing else now. */
      if (long_options[option_index].flag != 0)
        break;
      printf ("option %s", long_options[option_index].name);
      if (optarg)
        printf (" with arg %s", optarg);
      printf ("\n");
      break;
    case 'b':
      puts ("option -b\n");
      break;
    case 's':
      puts ("option -s\n");
      break;
    case '?':
      /* getopt_long already printed an error message. */
      break;

    default:
      abort ();
    }
    }

  if (verbose_flag)
    puts ("verbose flag is set");

  /* Print any remaining command line arguments (not options). */
  if (optind < argc)
    {
      printf ("non-option ARGV-elements: ");
      while (optind < argc)
    printf ("%s ", argv[optind++]);
      putchar ('\n');
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Related:

- <s>[Which command line commands style do you prefer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367309/which-command-line-commands-style-do-you-prefer)</s>
- [What is the general syntax of a Unix shell command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160083/)

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the getopt library; it's pretty much the gold standard for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `getopt()`, you may also consider using `argp_parse()` (an alternative interface to the same library).

From [libc manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libc/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html#Parsing-Program-Arguments):

> `getopt` is more standard (the
>   short-option only version of it is a
>   part of the POSIX standard), but using
>   `argp_parse` is often easier, both for
>   very simple and very complex option
>   structures, because it does more of
>   the dirty work for you.

But I was always happy with the standard `getopt`.

N.B. GNU `getopt` with `getopt_long` is GNU LGPL.

Comment: "getopt is GNU LGPL": That depends on the getopt. It has been implemented several times. The one in Mac OS X is BSD licensed.

Comment: And AT&T released one in the mid-80s into the public domain, or something very close to the public domain.  D McKee's point is very valid - GNU getopt() [and getopt_long()] are LGPL (or, older versions are GPL); not all versions of getopt() are GPL or LGPL.

Answer (score 4):

Other have hit this one on the head:

- the standard arguments to `main(int argc, char **argv)` give you direct access to the command line (after it has been mangled and tokenized by the shell)
- there are very standard facility to parse the command line: `getopt()` and `getopt_long()`

but as you've seen the code to use them is a bit wordy, and quite idomatic. I generally push it out of view with something like:

```
typedef
struct options_struct {
   int some_flag;
   int other_flage;
   char *use_file;
} opt_t;
/* Parses the command line and fills the options structure, 
 * returns non-zero on error */
int parse_options(opt_t *opts, int argc, char **argv);
```

Then first thing in main:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
   opt_t opts;
   if (parse_options(&opts,argc,argv)){
      ...
   } 
   ...
}
```

Or you could use one of the solutions suggested in [Argument-parsing helpers for C/UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189972/argument-parsing-helpers-for-c-unix/).