# C++ : Read a file name from the command line and utilize it in my file

Tags: c++, file

How can I read a filename from the command line and utilize it in my C++ code file?

ex: `./cppfile inputFilename outputFilename`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498320/pass-arguments-into-c-program-from-command-line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass arguments into C program from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498320/pass-arguments-into-c-program-from-command-line)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string inFile = "";
    string outFile = "";
    if( argc == 3 ) {
      inFile = argv[1];
      outFile = argv[2];
    }
    else {
      cout << "Usage: ./cppfile InputFile OutputFile\n";
      return 1;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Note that `argv[0]` is the program name; you probably need to check for `argc == 3` and use `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`.

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot.
Now when I'm using the filenames, can I do something like this:
`ifstream inFile;
inFile.open(argv[1]);`
?

Comment: You also need to include `iostream`, `string` and need to qualify with `std`.

Comment: You could turn it around and issue the error `if (argc != 3)`, and then initialise the strings directly: `std::string inFile(argv[1]);`, etc.