# How to use command line arguments to change a bool value

Tags: c, command-line

I have an assignment where My program is to be able to take one optional command line argument, the -d flag. And if this flag is entered, it is to change my global variable, bool debugMode from 0 to 1. I was told it would be similar to this :

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)
```

But I don't know how to properly implement it so that when it is ran with -d, it changes the bool from false to true.

My global variable is `bool debugMode = 0` if that is worth mention.

Comment: Look up `[c] getopt` on SO; there will be many examples.

Comment: `if(argc > 1) debugMode  = 1`;

Comment: You should be using `bool debugMode = false;`, should you not?  And then setting it to `true`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I am to check that they put in -d though, not just an argument

Comment: You said "one optional argument" so either it's there or it is not.

Comment: The question I chose as a duplicate shows a boolean option in the top-voted answer.  Another question that would help similarly is [Pass arguments into C program from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498320/).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what library would i include  besides stdbool.h to make it? Because my compiler underlined it when I made it false.

Comment: @WeatherVane: No; if the argument is `epistemology`, then it is not `-d` and an error message is in order.  Similarly, it might be `-h` or something else that is not `-d`.

Comment: Sorry about my simplification it's getting late here.

Comment: If you're compiling with a C compiler, `<stdbool.h>` is all you need to get `bool`, `true`, `false` defined.  If it doesn't define them, then there is a serious problem.  I'm blithely assuming you're compiling with C99 or later since you said you're using `bool`.  Indeed, if you have `bool`, you should have `true` and `false` always, unless you are somehow defining `bool` for yourself.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it works now with false, I'm not sure why it underlined it before.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I also don't really understand what the first answer is doing in the link you posted.

Comment: Hmmm...the relevant bit is: `bool isCaseInsensitive = false; int opt; … while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "ilw")) != -1) { switch (opt) { case 'i': isCaseInsensitive = true; break; …` —— and that has a Boolean variable `isCaseInsensitive` that is initialized to `false`, and then a standard loop using the `getopt()` function to test the flag `i` (you'd want a `d` in the string passed to `getopt()`, and `case 'd':` in the switch), with a switch which spots when `-i` is passed (because `getopt()` returns `i`) and sets `isCaseInsensitive` to `true`. What's the complication you have problems with?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The things that were confusing me the most were the switch cases and the stuff happening in them

Comment: OK.  Well, you should look at the POSIX specification for [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) sometime (and then the GNU version of [`getopt()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html)).  The key point is that you list the options in a string passed as the third argument to `getopt()` with a colon after the option letter if the option takes an argument (so you need `"d"` as the third argument), and `getopt()` returns either the option letter or an indicator of 'no more options' (`-1`) or an error. The switch analyzes this.

Comment: `bool debugMode = (argc == 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "-d") == 0);`