# Start C program with variable from NodeJS

Tags: javascript, c, node.js

What is the easiest way to send variable from nodeJS to C program (NOT C++)? And run this C program after receiving a variable?

app.js :

```
 var test = 1;
```

test.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>     
int main()
{
  int node_variable;
  printf("Value from nodeJS is %d", node_variable);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you do mean by "send variable"? You can pass values as arguments to C program.

Comment: Pass it as a command line argument => [Pass arguments into C program from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498320/pass-arguments-into-c-program-from-command-line)

Comment: Yes, you're right! I mean pass values to C program..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nodejs `child_process` module to pass your arguments to your C program (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775088/is-it-possible-to-execute-an-external-program-from-within-node-js) for instance).

app.js:

```
var test = 1;
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('./test.bin '+test, function callback(error, stdout, stderr){console.log(stdout);});
```

test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  printf("value of test: %s\n", argv[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Assuming `test.bin` is the program built from `test.c`, executing the javascript file makes the compiled program display the value of test (here, "1"). Be careful the value of the variable `test` is considered as a single (not empty) argument.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! But I have a question: can i display this printf from c in the console? Because now i get empty line..

Comment: Ok, i got it :D forgot to compile... 
gcc test.c -o test

Comment: The code from the C program is not directly printed to the standard output ; it is sent to the callback method using the `stdout` parameter. To write it in the console, just call `console.log(stdout);` in the callback method, like in my example.