# Can I pass parameters to main() in C

Tags: c

Im not sure about how it works but is it possible to pass parameters to a main() function like any other function in C? If so, please explain how it works?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass arguments into C program from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498320/pass-arguments-into-c-program-from-command-line)

Comment: Notably, the application programmer does not get to decide the format of main. Only the compiler can do that. It is required to support `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` if the compiler is a "conforming hosted implementation" (meaning C compliant compiler for programs running on an OS). It may additionally support compiler-specific forms, in which case you have to read the compiler documentation to find out which ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "pass parameters" to it because you can't call it per-se. It's the entry point of your application. It gets parameters from the *parent process* via the operating system.

`int main(int argc, char** argv)` is how you receive the arguments. How you "send" them is done by an `exec` call of some variety, like `execv()`.

This is how your shell sends in arguments, so if you run:

```sh
./myprogram arg1 arg2
```

Then you have those arguments available. Note that `argv[0]` is the name of the program or the "zeroth" argument, which in this example is the `"./myprogram"` part.

Comment: What exactly makes it so that you can't call it? Insofar I know, you can also call it like any other function.

Comment: @EmanuelP If you call `main()` from a function called from `main()` you're asking for runaway recursion. If you make it so it can be called recursively I have no idea why you'd go through that trouble, it just doesn't make any sense. There's a lot of things you can *technically* do in C, but which are so outside the realm of convention for all purposes they should not be done. That's why I say "per-se".