# C - read/write form a file having a dynamic name

Tags: c, file-io

I want to make a C program which will be called with some parameters; Each parameter will represent a filename and I want to write some stuffs in each of them.

```
FILE * h0;    
h0 = fopen(argv[0],"w");    
char buffer[100] = "something here\n";    
fprintf(h0,buffer);    
fclose(h0);
```

For C++ there is something called c_str() but I didn't manage to use it here.
Any tips how to handle it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C - reading command line parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157337/c-reading-command-line-parameters)

Comment: (Fixed your formatting: the correct way to format code is to indent it 4 spaces, you can do this by selecting your code and pressing the button labelled `{}`)

Comment: so what is the problem? add some error checking code and are you not good to go?

Comment: I think all is well here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file name is exactly a C string (null terminated array of char) and you've already answered your own question (you don't need anything like c_str in C), since you open the file and you write in it. The `argc` tells you how many arguments there are in the command line, the name of the program inclusive and it is at `argv[0]`. So you need a loop, like

```
const char *your_stuff = "something here\n";
for(i = 1; i < argc; i++)
{
   FILE *h = fopen(argv[i], "w");
   if (h) {
     fputs(your_stuff, h);
     fclose(h);
   }
}
```

or something like that.

Comment: so, the problem was that i tried to write to argv[0]; thanks a lot - problem solved

Answer (score 1):

You should look at how the command line arguments are formed:

http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html

Then have a look at your `argv[0]`.