# C - Using "&variable" in printf()

Tags: c

I am running this program with two command line arguments: `10` and `test`. It works as intended when I use:

```
printf("C = %s\n\n", &C);
```

but not when I use:

```
printf("C = %s\n\n", C);
```

and I can't understand why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

    int N = 0;
    char C = '\0';

    sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &N);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%s", &C);

    printf("N = %d\n\n", N);
    printf("C = %s\n\n", &C);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `sscanf(argv[2], "%s", &C);` is undefined behaviour : you don't have enough room to store the result whatever it is. It works by mere luck

Comment: You should learn basics of C programming language.

Comment: `C` is a single character and should be printed out using `%c` not `%s`

Comment: use `char c[10];` alongside `sscanf(argv[2], "%9s", C);`

Comment: You allocate a variable to hold a `char` and then try to get it to hold a string.

Comment: I see, big mistake I should be using: char C[10];

Answer (score 1):

I changed to the code below and seems to be working. I changed char C = '\0' to char C[10] so C is a string and not a character and removed ampersand (&) operator from printf("C = %s\n\n", &C).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

    int N = 0;
    char C[10];

    sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &N);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%s", C);

    printf("N = %d\n\n", N);
    printf("C = %s\n\n", C);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: @Yonlif *"explain to him"* It's the OP. :)

Comment: I mean that he should add something but just code @HolyBlackCat .

Comment: are you sure 10 is large enough to hold the string though? That is only big enough to hold 9 characters plus the NUL terminator at the end.

Comment: the string was "test", so 10 should be enough

Answer (score 0):

As I see it there are several problems in your code and in order to fix it you will need to change it alot. I don't believe that someone will do this for you, and I won't as well because everybody need to learn.

Google is your best friend!

Before asking question in Stack Overflow check how to do what you want to do online.

For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157337/c-reading-command-line-parameters) you can find a great answer about how to properly get command line parameters.

And [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm) you can see the difference between with or without '&' and what does it mean.

Good luck