# How to compare string from parameter in C?

Tags: c, character, parameter-passing

I am writing a program that takes two input parameters the first input parameter MUST be "-t", the second can be any number.

In order for the program to proceed, it must first check if the first parameter is "-t"

so for example, I would run it by typing "./a.out -t 45"

I tried to do this using the following:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *par ;
    par = argv[1];

    if(par == "-t"){
         printf("The parameter is: %s \n, The program will proceed" , par);
    } else {
         printf("Incorrect input \n");
         exit(1);   
    }

    // continue program
}
```

However I always get "Incorrect input no matter what, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The variable "par" is a character array, and the parameter
that I'm comparing it to is a character array so shouldn't the first part of the if statement execute instead of the else?

I looked here: [C - reading command line parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157337/c-reading-command-line-parameters)

but it wasn't much help. I can print the parameter just fine, I just can't compare it.

Comment: You should grab a beginner's text book on C and learn how strings work in C. There is a set of string functions in standard library. Including functions to compare strings.

Comment: `strcmp` should help.

Comment: Hmm, it's still not working I'm getting true no matter what I enter in as an argument, what format is the argument? is it a string/int/char?

Comment: Never mind, I got it work!