# How do i know if my args[] string is char type?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

I am writing program in which the first argument must be `char` type and the second one an `int`. I already wrote the code for the `int` type but can't make it for the `char`. I have searched everywhere, but I cannot find an answer to my problem, here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 3){
         puts("Error: Invalid number of arguments\n");
         exit(0);
    }
    if(argv[1] ??){
         puts("Error: First argument not a char type\n");
         exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you receive the arguments from the command line via `char *argv[]`, each element of the `argv` array is the pointer to a standard C string, terminated as C strings are with a `0` byte. They are string representations of the command line arguments. If one of them represents an integer, you have to apply a string-to-integer function and check the results. There's nothing more special about `char *argv[]` which is why you cannot find anything after all the searching. However, you can Google "process command line arguments in C" and find useful information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C - reading command line parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157337/c-reading-command-line-parameters)

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "char type"? All arguments are basically char type, as they are strings. Do you mean "not a number"? Or "letters from A to Z"? You could use `isalpha()` or `!isdigit()` on the first character of your string.

Comment: regarding this kind of statement: `puts("Error: Invalid number of arguments\n");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, however, `puts()` outputs to `stdout`.  For the checks of the parameter list, suggest using: `fprintf( stderr, "...\n";)   Also, when the incorrect number of parameters have been passed to `main()`  it is the normal practice to output a `USAGE` message showing the user how it should be done.  Similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <string> <integer>\n", argv[0] );`,

Answer (score 1):

The reason is explained above by lurker.
If you want to validate the first argument is a char from the command line, isascii might be what you are looking for.  More validation on argv[1] should be done to avoid Segmentation fault.

```
    if (argv[1][1]!='\0'||!isascii(argv[1][0])) {
        puts("Error: First argument not a char type\n");
        exit(0);
}
```

"       isascii()
              checks  whether  c is a 7-bit unsigned char value that fits into
              the ASCII character set."
and don't forget to `#include <ctype.h>`