# This code emulates command ls|cat -n, but i need to transmit the needed directory through stdin instead of ".", how can i do it?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main() {

    struct dirent *de;

    DIR *dr;
    int i = 1;

    dr = opendir("."); // need to get directory through stdin insted of this 

    if (dr == NULL) printf("Could not open directory");

    while (((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL))
    {
        printf("\t%d. %s\n", i, de -> d_name);
        i++;
    }

    closedir(dr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about `argv[1]` ? (seems the logical choice to me)

Comment: I am a newbie in coding, so i don't really understand what you mean. I just want program to work show list of files and sub-directories after this ./a.out < directory or pwd|./a.out

Comment: Maybe you mean int main(int argc, int *argv[])

.....

opendir(argv[1]);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157337/c-reading-command-line-parameters/5157549 may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read it from stdin and use in place of `"."`. Here is the full example

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(){

        struct dirent *de;
        char dirbuf[BUFSIZ] = {0};
        DIR *dr;
        int i = 1;

        puts("Chose the directory: ");
        if (fgets(dirbuf, BUFSIZ, stdin) == NULL) {
                perror("fgets");
                exit(-1);
        }
        dirbuf[strlen(dirbuf)-1] = '\0'; // remove \n

        dr = opendir(dirbuf); // need to get directory through stdin insted of this 

        if (dr == NULL) {
                perror("opendir");
                exit(-1);
        }

        while(((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL))
        {

                printf("\t%d. %s\n", i, de -> d_name);
                i++;
        }

        closedir(dr);

        return 0;

}
```

Comment: Safer removal of (possible) trailing *ENTER*: `dirbuf[strcspn(dirbuf, "\n\r")] = 0;`

Comment: Suggestion: initialize `i` with `0` and swap the statements inside the `while`. Reason is that after the while `i` has the number of entries printed (no real advantage in this short program but may be easier with longer programs).