# How can I get arguments from standard input in C?

Tags: c

I have a string that I want to execute in C file and I'd like to get the string from standard input.

```
echo "Here is some random text.\n" | ./main.c
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157337/c-reading-command-line-parameters

Comment: `fread` from `stdin` or `read` from `STDIN_FILENO`?

Comment: I thought that argument of the function is different from standard inputs.

Comment: @MichaelHajný What argument to which function are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read from [`stdin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/std_streams) like any other [`FILE`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/FILE) stream.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char line[BUFSIZ];
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    printf("stdin: %s", line);
}
```