# getopt_long long options work but not short options

Tags: c, getopt, getopt-long

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [getopt_long() — proper way to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489093/getopt-long-proper-way-to-use-it)

I'm struggling with getopt_long in my C program.  Code:

```
const struct option long_options[] = { 
    { "help", 0, NULL, 'h' },
    { "num", 1, NULL, 'n' },
    { NULL, 0, NULL, 0 } 
};  
do {
    next_option = getopt_long(argc, argv, short_options, 
        long_options, NULL);
    switch(next_option) {
        case 'h':
            print_usage(stdout, 0); 
        case 'n':
            printf("num %s\n", optarg);
            break;
        case '?':
            print_usage(stderr, 1); 
            break;
        default:
            abort();
    }   
} while(next_option != -1);
```

This works:

```
./a.out --num 3
num 3
```

This works (why?!):

```
./a.out --n 3            
num 3
```

This does not:

```
./a.out -n 3  
num (null)
```

so long option works, short does with two '-'s (why?) and the short option doesn't work (`printf` prints `NULL`), why is this?  Many thanks.

Comment: What _are_ the short options? Please include `short_options` as well.

Comment: Funny that you omit the most relevant piece of code ;)

Comment: const char * const short_options = "hn";

Comment: use getopt instead of get_long_opt if you want to get -option instead of --option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to pass a short options string too, something like this:

```
const char *short_options ="hn:";
```

Note the `:` means `-n` accepts an argument.