# How to parse arguments in a Win32 Console Application?

Tags: winapi, arguments

everyone. I know there are a lot of related threads, but I can't understand them very well, so I decided to write my own.

I am trying to write a Win32 Console Application, and this is I would like to do:

Let's suppose my name app is: MyApp.exe, so I want every time I type in the command line:

```
MyApp.exe -W Hello
```

My app writes "Hello" in the output. Same as other arguments. Basically, I want to control every argument that I want but I don't know how to do that.

This is all I have:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv [])
{

    int count;


    printf("This program was called with  \"%s\". \n", argv[1]);
    printf("\n");

    system("Pause");

}
```

I mean, I know every argument is in the argv array, but I don't know how to parse that, like:

```
if(argv[1] == "-W")
```

It does not work.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Assuming you forgot the "C" language tag on this question,  tag on this, take a look at [this possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642732/parsing-command-line-arguments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using C, use the [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) function:

```
if(strcmp(argv[1], "-W") == 0) { /* the first argument is -W */ }
```

If you're using C++, use the [`operator==`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operators/):

```
if(std::string(argv[1]) == "-W") { /* the first argument is -W */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do string compares using `==`, you need something like

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "-W") == 0)
```

For case-insensitive comparisons, you need to use `_stricmp()` instead.

See this MSDN article on [String Manipulation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0151s4x.aspx).