# Using getopt triggers all cases in one

Tags: c, getopt

I'm trying to use getopt in order to run two different functions depending on the arguments given.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i;
    int identify;
        while ((identify = getopt(argc, argv, "c:")) != -1) {
            switch (identify) {
                case 'c':
                    for (i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
                        readerC(argv[i]);
                    }
                default:
                    for (i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
                        reader(argv[i]);
                    }
            }
        }
    return(0);
}
```

The purpose is that, if the command included "-c", then it would run the "readerC" function. If there were no arguments passed, then it would read the "reader" function.

I've revised the above function multiple times, but I can't seem to be able to run the "reader" function when running the command with no arguments (there is no output). Previously, putting in -c would run the readerC command as required, but after messing around with it, it now runs the readerC function followed by the reader function.

I tried changing "default:" to "case ':'" and "case '?'" but that hasn't worked either. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: how many arguments are you passing in the main method?

Comment: @SudiptaKumarSahoo It takes any number of files

Comment: can you provide an example of input arguments that contains "-c" as well?

Comment: See, amongst other similar questions, [Parsing command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642732/parsing-command-line-arguments).

Comment: @SudiptaKumarSahoo ./function -c file1 file2

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for the link and comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence for a `main()` program handling options is often:

- Initialization
- Option parsing
- Do the real work

You should process the options with `getopt()`, then process the file arguments.  You also need to include `break` in your `switch` statement as C does not break automatically between cases.

Hence, you might end up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void reader(const char *file);
static void readerC(const char *file);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    void (*function)(const char *arg) = reader;
    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "c")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'c':
            function = readerC;
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Unrecognized option %c\n", optopt);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    if (optind == argc)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-c] file ...\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = optind; i < argc; i++)
    {
        (*function)(argv[i]);   // The old-fashioned way
        // function(argv[i]);   // The more modern way
    }

    return(0);
}
```

If you're not comfortable with function pointers yet, then you can use a flag instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void reader(const char *file);
static void readerC(const char *file);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int cflag = 0;
    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "c")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'c':
            cflag = 1;
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Unrecognized option %c\n", optopt);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    if (optind == argc)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-c] file ...\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = optind; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (cflag)
            readerC(argv[i]);
        else
            reader(argv[i]);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the flags are working well. Although when trying ./function -c singlefile.txt, I get "Usage: ./function [-c] fille..." error. I'm going to mess with it for a bit, but yours is the best answer. Thank you again :)

Comment: You can tell the code hadn't been past a compiler; there was a typo `consst` instead of `const`.  I also put a `:` after the `c` in the option specification passed to `getopt()`.  That caused the 'usage' error you found, because the `-c` used the file name as its option argument (though it ignored it), leaving you with no extra arguments to process.  I've amended the code; I believe it should work now.  Apologies for the mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add `break` statements. Without a `break`, control simply falls through to the next case. Here is the code with `break` statements inserted into the relevant places:

```
while ((identify = getopt(argc, argv, "c:")) != -1) {
    for (i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
        switch (identify) {
            case 'c':
                for (i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
                    readerC(argv[i]);
                }
                break;
            default:
                for (i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
                    reader(argv[i]);
                }
                break; /* not really needed but for completeness */
        }
    }
}
```

Also, it seems like you are using the same `i` for all nested loops. Are you sure that's what you want? You might also want to have a look at the `optarg` variable which points to the argument corresponding to the currently parsed option.

Maybe also read about how `getopt` works again because it seems like you haven't quite understood it. These loops you wrote are somewhat strange.

Comment: That seems to fix it so -c only prints the first one, but how do I get it to run reader if there are none?
The loops are strange due to me trying to fix it multiple times, I've been working on this function for a long while now.

Comment: The `for` loop shouldn't be where it is.  The code needs to parse the options (`-c` or not) first, then process the non-option arguments.   There should be a `while` loop for processing the options, and a `for` loop for processing the non-option arguments.

Comment: @AndrewRaleigh Set a flag if `-c` has been supplied. Call `reader()` if the flag has not been set.