# How to search for command line arguments in C?

Tags: c

I have compiled and run a C code (a lot of files) but I need to understand the physical meaning of the command line arguments.I run code like this

```
./testmt signal1 3 5 1 1
```

where
signal1 is the input file

How to search multiple .c files in order to find command line arguments(hopefully with commented lines)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing command-line arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642732/parsing-command-line-arguments)

Comment: find where `main` is and start there (probably `int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {`). Performing a `grep` on the source files should get you there.

Comment: How are we supposed to know what your program does?

Comment: You do not need to search multiple files, it is right there in `main(int argc, char *argv[])` and there are many easy to find examples. The first argument is usually the executable's name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is operating system specific. I guess you are on Linux or some other Posix system. Read first [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). Read also about [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29). Be aware that your [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) is expanding the arguments (and after expansion calling the [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) system call....). If you shell is `bash` (and actually that behavior is mandated by POSIX) read about [*Shell Operation*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Operation.html) then about [*Shell expansions*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Operation.html). Read also the [*Program Arguments*](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html) chapter of `libc` documentation. See also [*my answer*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/307472/40065) on "good habits for designing command line arguments?".

The `main` function (of signature `int main(int argc, char**argv);`, and such a [possible] signature is defined by the C standards) - of the program started by `execve` - gets the positive argument count and a `NULL` terminated array of strings. So in your case (`./testmt signal1 3 5 1 1`) you get `argc=6` and `argv[0]` is `"./testmt"`, `argv[1]` is `"signal"`, `argv[2]`  is `"3"`, etc... `argv[5]` is the last `"1"` and `argv[6]` is `NULL`.

So dive into your code, and look for `main`.

<sup>PS. AFAIK, on Windows the behavior is probably different. The program (not the shell) is expanding the arguments (actually, probably done in startup files, before they call `main`). But I know nothing about Windows. See also *[Operating Systems: Three easy pieces](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)*.</sup>