# How does execlp work exactly?

Tags: unix, exec

So I am looking at my professor's code that he handed out to try and give us an idea of how to implement >, <, | support into our unix shell. I ran his code and was amazed at what actually happened.

```
if( pid == 0 )
{
    close(1);                                   // close
    fd = creat( "userlist", 0644 );             // then open
    execlp( "who", "who", NULL );               // and run
    perror( "execlp" );
    exit(1);
}
```

This created a userlist file in the directory I was currently in, with the "who" data inside that file. I don't see where any connection between fd, and execlp are being made. How did execlp manage to put the information into userlist? How did execlp even know userlist existed?

Answer (score 1):

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). It has several chapters related to the issue. And we cannot explain all this in a few sentences. See also the [standard stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) and [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) wikipages.

First, all the [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (see [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) for a list, and read the documentation of every individual system call that you are using) your program is doing should be tested against failure. But assume they all succeed. After `close(1);` the [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) 1 (`STDOUT_FILENO`) is free. So `creat("userlist",0644)` is likely to re-use it, hence `fd` is 1; you have redirected your *stdout* to the newline created `userlist` file.

At last, you are calling [execlp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execlp.3.html) which will call [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). When successful, your entire process is restarted with the new executable (so a fresh [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) is given to it), and its *stdout* is still the `userlist` file descriptor. In particular (unless `execve` fails) the `perror` call is *not reached*.

So your code is a bit what a shell running `who > userlist` is doing; it does a redirection of *stdout* to `userlist` and runs the `who` command.

If you are coding a shell, use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) -notably with `-f` option- to understand what system calls are done. Try also `strace -f /bin/sh -c ls` to look into the behavior of a shell. Study also the source code of existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) shells (e.g. `bash` and `sash`).

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40982829/841108) and the references I gave there.

Answer (score 0):

`execlp` knowns nothing. Before execing stdout was closed and a file opened, so the descriptor is the one corresponding to stdout (opens always returns the lowest free descriptor). At that point the process has an "stdout" plugged to the file. Then exec is called and this replaces to whole address space, but some properties remains as the descriptors, so know the code of `who` is executed with an stdout that correspond to the file. This is the way redirections are managed by shells.

Remember that when you use `printf` (for example) you never specify what stdout exactly is... That can be a file, a terminal, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Basile Starynkevitch correctly explained:

> After `close(1);` the [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) 1 (`STDOUT_FILENO`) is free. So `creat("userlist",0644)` is likely to re-use it…

This is because, as Jean-Baptiste Yunès wrote, "*opens always returns the lowest free descriptor*".

It should be stressed that the *professor's code* only *likely* works; it fails if file descriptor 0 is closed.