# How do I can write a program where I can add information just like commands in Ubuntu (ex: program -u "Hello World")

Tags: c++, c, python-2.7

I am interested in writing a program in C or Python and add information to my software just like in command line, maybe I'm not explaining so good but what I want looks like this:

Ex: myProgram -u "Hello World"

Then after pressing enter to show my message on screen

Comment: Are you asking how you can access the command line arguments given to a C or Python program?

Comment: Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments

Comment: C: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642732/parsing-command-line-arguments

Comment: Yes, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

In c, we can receive "arguments" from the operating system in the following manner:

```
int main(int argc,char **argv){
    printf("Quantity of arguments: %i\n",argc);
    for(int i=0;i<argc;++i){
        printf("Argument %i: %s\n",i,argv[i]);
    }
}
```