# How to group args with a parameter with getopt()

Tags: c, linux

I need to use two args with a parameter. But if I use the two args grouped then I want to enter the parameter only 1 time.

For example

```
./mycode -a 45

./mycode -b 45  

./mycode -ab 45
```

Comment: I don't think `getopt()` supports this.

Comment: I suggest to simply *not do this*. This isn't how argument parsing works for basically any other argument parsing scheme.

Comment: This could make sense if it's something that looks like tar (i.e. `tar xvf file.tar`). Not sure getopt can do this though.

Answer (score 2):

As barmar commented,. getopt doesn't support this.  It's one of those things "Wouldn't that be cool?" but do it 'by hand' in C is your only option.  Not worth it IMHO.  Here's a link to a longer S.O. thread [describing your options for option processing:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642732/parsing-command-line-arguments)