# Access to bash local variable in c

Tags: c, bash, ls

I'm trying to remake an ls command in C; I need to replicate a "total" row if directory content is listed (exactly how Unix ls does).
I know it's the sum of file size(without considering soft link and inner directory contents), rounded up, divided by the local variable BLOCKSIZE, correct me if it's wrong.
The questions are: what BLOCKSIZE exactly is, how can i check it from terminal and how get its value in c.
PS: my c program has to be runned from bash like ./program [options] {files}, I can not pass anything else to argv in main.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can pass it to your program as a command-line argument, or you can export it to your program as an environment variable.

Comment: thanks a lot for suggest, so to export it is something like `export VAR` , right?

Comment: Right, it depends on the shell you use, but for sh and bash you would use `export`.  Then you can use `getenv` from your C program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Block-size.html):

> The default block size is chosen by examining the following environment variables in turn; the first one that is set determines the block size.
>   ....
>   BLOCKSIZE

`BLOCKSIZE` is an environment variable. You get the value of environment variables using the C standard [`getenv()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/getenv) call.

```
 const char *blocksizestr = getenv("BLOCKSIZE");
 if (blocksizestr == NULL) { /* no BLOCKSIZE variable */ }
 int blocksize = atoi(blocksizestr);
```

Also note that `BLOCKSIZE` does not affect `ls` directly. It's nowhere referenced from [coreutils/ls.c](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c#L2117). `LS_BLOCK_SIZE` and `BLOCK_SIZE` are. The `BLOCKSIZE` environment variable is used inside [gnulib/human.c](https://github.com/rofl0r/gnulib/blob/master/lib/human.c#L418) library inside the `human_options()` and from `human_readable()` functions. The `human_readable()` is used by gnu utilities to print human readable output.

Answer (score 1):

Look up POSIX [`statvfs()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/statvfs.html) and
[`<sys/statvfs.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_statvfs.h.html).  The member described as shown sounds like the information you need:

- `unsigned long f_bsize` — File system block size

That way, you don't need to rely on the user for the information; you can get the system to tell your program what you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

`--block-size` is a [command line argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642732/parsing-command-line-arguments-in-c) to `ls`:

[man ls(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html):

> `--block-size=SIZE`
>   with `-l`, scale sizes by `SIZE` when printing them; e.g.,
>   `--block-size=M`; see SIZE format below

Comment: Maybe I forgot an important information (i'm gonna correct it in the question), my c program has to be runned from terminal with some options and file (something like ./program.c -l -R file1 dir1 file2 ecc.) but just this. So I need to get it from c with system call or something similar. Thanks anyway for your quick answer.