# program must take a port# as an argument from the CmdLine Socket prog

Tags: c

I am new to C Network programming and I need to update the program to take port# as argument from the command line but I keep getting a segmentation fault error. Not sure how to fix. any help will be appreciated.

Here is the Server program code where the port number is hard coded

```
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);
```

This is the Client program code

```
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);
```

How to do I change it to start receiving port # as input from cmdline

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_command_line_arguments.htm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing command-line arguments in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642732/parsing-command-line-arguments-in-c)