# How to modify/use command line argument in main function if it is a string?

Tags: c

I want to compare the different elements of a command-line argument. It would be entered all together resulting in the string being found at `argv[1]`.  However, I am not sure how to compare the elements and individual characters as I am looking for repetitions.

If I compared `[2]` to `[3]` in the string, there would be nothing there as only 1 string is entered in the command line argument and I need to compare the characters found within that string `argv[1]`.  I am unable to include spaces so I wouldn't be able to compare `argv[2]` to `argv[1]`.

Comment: The first argument is `argv[1]` and its individual characters are `argv[1][0]`, `argv[1][1]`, `argv[1][2]`, `argv[1][3]`, etc. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Though it is possible to parse the arguments yourself, you are better off using a library for this, e.g. argp http://nongnu.askapache.com/argpbook/step-by-step-into-argp.pdf Relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642732/parsing-command-line-arguments-in-c

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question. Please provide a [example], show us your input, what you get, and what you expect instead.

Answer (score 0):

Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c).

If you code for Linux, read also documentation of [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), in particular the section on [parsing program arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html).

You could also use [strcmp(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html) to compare your program argument to some fixed constant string.

The program arguments are given to your `main` function, traditionally defined as `int main(int argc, char**argv)`. They are *always* strings (of different addresses), and on POSIX you are practically certain that `argc>0`, `argv[0]` is a non-empty string (somehow the name of the program), all `argv[i]` with i >= 0 and i < argc are non-null, and `argv[argc]` is `NULL`.

You could code inside your `main` something like

```
 if (argc>1 && !strcmp(argv[1], "foo")) {
    /// handle `foo` as first program argument
 }
```

I would recommend to study for inspiration the source code of [GNU findutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/) or of [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/).

**I don't recommend *modifying* program arguments** with e.g. some code like `strcpy(argv[1], "bar")`. It is not portable, perhaps forbidden, and certainly unreadable and brittle.

If you are on Linux, see also [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) about `/proc/self/cmdline`